# Override of the same function with inherited class

Tags: c++, overriding, overloading

I have this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class GenericMove {};

class SwapMove: public GenericMove {};

class SoftConstraint {
  public:
    virtual int evaluate(GenericMove& gm) = 0;
};

class M1: public SoftConstraint {
  public:
    int evaluate(GenericMove& gm){ return 1; }
    int evaluate(SwapMove& gm){ return 2; }
};

int main () {
  M1 m1;
  GenericMove* swapmove = new SwapMove();
  cout << "Hello " << m1.evaluate(*swapmove) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I would like to discern between GenericMove and SwapMove in the `evaluate` function of M1 , so I would like that the main prints "Hello 2".

Is there a way to distinguish that `swapmove` is not only a simple GenericMove but it is also SwapMove inside M1?

Is that possible in C++?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not directly possible in C++ AFAIK, but you can use [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) to achieve your desired result.

```
class GenericMove;
class SwapMove;

class SoftConstraint {
public:
    virtual int evaluate(GenericMove& move) = 0;
    virtual int evaluate(SwapMove& move) = 0;
};

class M1 : public SoftConstraint {
public:
    int evaluate(GenericMove& move) { return 1; }
    int evaluate(SwapMove& move) { return 2; }
};

class GenericMove {
public:
    virtual int evaluate(SoftConstraint& constraint) {
        return constraint.evaluate(*this);
    }
};

class SwapMove : public GenericMove {
public:
    int evaluate(SoftConstraint& constraint) {
        return constraint.evaluate(*this);
    }   
};

int main () {
  M1 m1;
  GenericMove* swapmove = new SwapMove();
  std::cout << "Hello " << swapmove->evaluate(m1) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Note that in my proposal you have to call the `evaluate` method of the move instance as opposed to calling the `evaluate` method of the constraint. But this could be changed easily.

Double dispatch exploits the fact that the static type of the `this` pointer is always the type to which the function using the `this` pointer belongs. In our example, the static type of `this` in `GenericMove::evaluate` is `GenericMove*`
, so the call to `SoftConstraint::evaluate` selects the function that takes a reference to an instance of `GenericMove` as its argument. On the other hand, the static type of `this` in `SwapMove::evaluate` is `SwapMove*`
, so the call to `SoftConstraint::evaluate` selects the function that takes a reference to an instance of `SwapMove` as its argument.

Double dispatch allows you to select a method using the type of the receiver of the call and the type of one argument.